# Swift: clear cache on switch to controllers

Tags: swift, controller, storyboard

I have strange problem

index.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // ...
    goToPage.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGoToPage(sender:))))
}

@objc func handleGoToPage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let pageController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page")
    self.present(pageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

page.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // ...
    pritData.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePritData(sender:))))
}

@objc func handlePritData(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("DATA")
}
```

1. i open application
2. i click on `goToPage` button and go to `page.swift`
3. i click `printData` and print `DATA`

Till this moment everything work fine

4. i back to `index.swift`
5. i click again on `goToPage` button and go to `page.swift`
6. i click `printData` and print `DATA` `DATA`

Why print twice `DATA` ?

If i back `index.swift` and click again and go to `page.swift`, my function in `page.swift` work multiple and print `DATA` multiple

For example, if 20 times i go to `page.swift` and click `printData`, print for me 20 times `DATA`

Why not clear cache or clear function cache for every open `page.swift` ?

Comment: **deinit** is called inside page.swift when you dismiss it ??

Comment: no, what is this ?